# A basic question about the Kolmogorov—Smirnov test and the $p$-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a pretty basic doubt about the KS test (two samples). From what I understand:

> We reject null hypothesis, under the confidence parameter $\alpha$, if the p-value (that is, the probability that the statistic takes a value $\geq$ observed, under the null hypothesis) is $\leq \alpha$
>   (Typically, $\alpha$ is set to 5%).
>
> So, in particular, the bigger the $\alpha$, the more likely we'll reject.

Here, in the Kolmogorov—Smirnov our statistic is the Kolmogorov distance $X\stackrel{\rm def}{=}d_K(\hat{p},\hat{q})$, where $\hat{p},\hat{q}$ are the empirical distributions obtained from our two samples.
We have a mapping $\alpha \mapsto c_\alpha$ (from the theoretical analysis of the distribution of $X$, under the assumption that our two unknown distributions $p,q$ are equal: $p=q$)
The two-sample KS test will reject the null hypothesis ($H_0\colon p=q$) if $X\geq c_\alpha$.

From the above, it is clear that $c_\alpha$ decreases when $\alpha$ increases.

Now, my question:

> Can I argue in any way about the guarantees I get for rejecting the alternative hypothesis, $p\neq q$? In other terms, what can I say from that $X$ about using $p\neq q$ as the null hypothesis $H_0$, instead of $p=q$?

Comment: Null hypothesis must be simple hypothesis, like $p = q$, because otherwise the distribution of test statistics cannot be determined. $p \ne q$ is a composite hypothesis and cannot be used as null.

Comment: @a_statistician It's quite possible to have composite nulls. The really big difficulty here is with the point alternative.

Comment: @Clement we have a number of posts on site about trying to put $\neq$ into the null of hypothesis tests. See whuber's comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210721/bernoulli-hypothesis-test-where-null-hypothesis-is-that-p-does-not-equal-p-0) for example (sorry I can't find a question with that information in an actual answer.

Comment: @Glen_b OK, in this case, what is the distribution of $(X|p \ne q)$?

Comment: @a_statistician That would be a case with a point alternative, which is where I said there'd be a problem. For a composite null to work, you need a composite alternative at least (and preferably the equality under the null). You don't have to have $\alpha$ associated with every point in the null, you need to be no higher than $\alpha$ everywhere.

Comment: @Glen_b It is interesting, but I still cannot follow you. Could you recommend some articles or books or something else, such that I can get familiar with this new idea?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks! That's more or less what I expected (and feared).

Comment: @a_statistician I'm simply contrasting a null of the form "$\mu \leq 0$ with alternative $\mu >0$ (which has both hypotheses composite and is commonly used) with your first comment above, which would suggest that it was ruled out. I can find a reference for that if you like. [In fact if the parameter space is discrete you could have a composite null and a point alternative, but I wasn't trying to get overly complex in discussion]

Comment: @Glen_b It is great if you can give me a reference.

Comment: @a_stat Composite nulls in 1) Casella & Berger (1990) *Statistical Inference*, Ch 8. E.g. see (i) p345, last 7 lines, starting "As another example, a consumer might"; (ii) p350, example 8.2.4; (iii) p355, example 8.2.7; (iv) p360 example 8.3.2 etc  2) Conover (1980) *Practical Nonparametric statistics, 2nd Ed*, (i) p76 8th line starting "Therefore in the assumed model..."; (ii) p96 (near bottom of page) hypotheses B and C. A different form of composite null arises null in goodness of fit testing e.g. 3) Smith (1993), *Into Statistics* p626 tests  H0: X ~ binomial(4,p) vs a general alternative

Comment: Some authors will present one tailed tests as equality nulls and one-sided alternatives (e.g. Wackerly, Mendenhall & Scheaffer, *Mathematical Statistics with Applications* does this, and there are definitely situations where this makes sense), but even then when they treat chi-squared goodness of fit tests of distributions with unspecified parameters, their nulls are unavoidably composite (e.g. Wackerly,M&S 5th ed p625 example 14.2 is one with a composite null, over the unspecified parameter $\lambda$, though they don't say so explicitly)